# Google's Chrome addons are not showing

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions

I have a few chrome adds installed and I am able to view them when I go to chrome://extensions. I have a total of 7 active add-ons, in my browser next to the address bar, I am able to see 3.

The four add-ons I do not see are Google Sheets, Google Docs, Google Docs offline, and Google Slides.

Why woulnd't these add-ons be appearing next to the address bar? Is there a limit to the amount of add-ons that can be shown in the browser or is there something specific about the behavior of google addons that makes them not show in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

From my research thus far, if an add-on is a browser action - then it will be added to the right of the address bar. It is very possible that these other add-ons are not defined as browser actions

Further reading : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction